# PHP 7.4 number_format still renders as string

Tags: arrays, php-7.4

This is my array $grand_total_payouts,

```
 array(5) { 
            [0]=> string(6) "120.00" 
            [1]=> string(8) "1,200.00" 
            [2]=> string(8) "1,347.50" 
            [3]=> string(5) "40.00" 
            [4]=> string(6) "200.00" 
           }
```

When I do this

```
   $value = '';
    foreach ($grand_total_provider_payouts as $payout) {
        $value = number_format($payout, 2, '.', ',' );
        var_dump($value);
    }
```

I get this.

```
 string(6) "120.00" 
 string(4) "1.00" 
 string(4) "1.00" 
 string(5) "40.00" 
 string(6) "200.00"
```

Why do [1] and [2] render as 1.0? And why do the numbers render as strings and not int?

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format
It should render as a number.

My ultimate goal is to sum these numbers.
What is the right way to convert the string to int?

Answer (score 1):

When you call number_format it return a string, because this is the expected behaviour, present number in currency format is a commom case.

1.0 to "US$ 1.00"

If you need perform math operations, don't use number_format before. Perform
all operations, so use number_format if you wish present formatted to view

Comment: The key was to not let the numbers in the array become strings, to begin with. Where the numbers were generated, I changed the code to create numbers instead of strings.

Comment: a simple cast is what are you looking  for? e.g: 
$value = "1.01";
$numberValue = (float) $value;
var_dump($numberValue); // prints: float(1.01)

Comment: The problem is the array. From an array, I was unable to change the string value. Like this string [0] => "1,307.50" can't be set to an int